# How can I draw a 3D plot for this function?

Tags: r

Can anybody help me how to plot an image or 3D plot for this function that the output is in array class?

```
mu <- function(x,y,t,par){
  return(par[1]+ par[2]*(x-t)+par[3]*x*t)
}

x <- seq(0,1,0.1)

y <- seq(0,1,0.1)

t <- seq(0,1,0.1)

mu.values <- array(NA, dim=c(length(x),length(y),length(t)))

for(i in 1:length(x)){

  for(j in 1:length(y)){

    for(k in 1:length(t)){

      mu.values[i,j,k] <- mu(x[i], y[j], t[k], par=c(0.25,0.25,0))

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, now including slices:

```r
library(reshape2)

library(plot3D)


m = melt(mu.values)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

scatter3D(x = m$Var1, y = m$Var2, z = m$Var3, colvar = m$value, pch = 16, cex = 0.1)

# contour slices

x <- y <- z <- 1:11

slicecont3D (x, y, z, ys = 1:11, colvar = mu.values, 
             theta = 60, border = "gray")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you have any suggestion for image in t slices?

Comment: When your question is answered it is customary to click on the accept answer option and upvote if you have sufficient reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer; which gives you a starter for what you are trying to do. Best if you have a look at the package documentation and experiment with the finer details to achieve what you want; good luck.